# Special triangle possible with just CSS (so I can change the border color)?

Tags: css, geometry, border

I have a sort of speech bubble: http://screencast.com/t/xy3xPHYlM with rounded corners and a triangle on the right of left (depending on `:nth-child(odd/even)`). The border and rounded corners are no problem with `border` and `border-radius`. But I'd like the triangle to be CSS as well, so I can change the border color of the entire thing. Currently the triangle is a sprite of two triangles (left and right).

I know triangles are possible with CSS (2 even): http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/eDdZb/ but those don't even look like it. Any way to make a triangle look like the one in the screenshot? I prefer using only `:before` and `:after` elements, but if needed I can add more.

[You can edit this fiddle if you'd like to try.](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/2xtNH/)

Comment: Hi, have you tried CSS tranform skew? And perhaps in combination with rotate. You should be able to "deformt" the :after element to match your design. (I tried to prepare a example, though I could not get skew working in JS fiddle :/ )

Comment: It seems that after applying a transformation there's no way of getting the box to appear on top of the skewed div (in Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/tkqYp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's pure CSS, it has to have a right angle. No way around that (that I know). If that's not a problem, then use two of them, one dark for the line, and one lighter on top and a pixel smaller to mask it.

This sounds really like you want some SVG as the easiest way to draw your lines with an easily configurable colour. It would clutter your markup a bit though, which it sounds you're trying to avoid.

*Edit*: if you allow yourself an extra unsemantic element for styling the border, you can manage the arrow. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xtNH/21/)—easily adapted to work in Chrome etc too.

Comment: SVG inside a stylesheet? With an SVG data URL? That sounds awesome and I want that! Something like `background: url(data:text/svg,<svg>...more awesome stuff here...</svg>)`? That what you mean?

Comment: Regarding the SVG it data urls, I think Opera was planning to support that; been a while since I've checked. Perhaps even Fx's rather awesome new framework handles that kind of thing in its SVG-anywhere model. Realistically though, I was thinking of cluttering the markup with two or three SVG elements. The colour of the funky border shape though would still be controlled just by the CSS.

Comment: In fact, for something more along the lines of what you were thinking, see edit above.

Comment: Awesome. You did it without the weird CSS triangle technique, but just with 1px borders and rotations. All I have to do is get the angles perfect and the colors right. Thanks man! (And I don't mind the unsemantic extra element (it's not even that bad).)

Comment: Not perfect though... The background colors etc have to be like the screen. There's a body background color, a text baloon background color and a border color. I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/sxXx3/ but didn't quite succeed. You can't seem to place `:after` and `:before` behind the containing element =(

Comment: Rudie, that's exactly why the extra element is needed. You can't put the pseudoelements behind their parent easily, so that's why I made the extra child element. You need them on the top-most container. [See final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxXx3/5/).

Comment: Perfect =) Stupid CSS. We need special-corners support in CSS4. Thanks man

Comment: This is why you should add code to your answer... Link is broken.